# How to test whether object "isEmpty()" if Object.prototype was modified?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I want to test whether an object is empty: `{}`. The following is typically used:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But suppose the `Object` prototype was added to as follows:

```
Object.prototype.Foo = "bar";
```

Tests:

```
alert(isEmpty({}));              // true
Object.prototype.Foo = "bar";
alert({}.Foo);                   // "bar" oh no...
alert(isEmpty({}));              // true  ...**huh?!**
```

I tried to nuke the object's prototype, change it's constructor, and all manner of such hacks. Nothing worked, but maybe I did it wrong (probable).

Comment: Actually I just realized that this question is probably incorrectly phrased, it should maybe be: _"how to test whether a prototype chain was changed"_?

Comment: ...and the only way I can think of is to hardcode every property for "Object", "Number", "Array", etc., and check that there is nothing outside of the known properties. Quite messy. Though I'd like to do this in a unit test to see that no one snuck something into the primitive types, which I've always been suspicious of (because it might blow up my code downstream and I would struggle to trace the problem).

Comment: read this : http://www.3site.eu/doc/

Comment: @PeterMarks — so how do you find a non-enumerable property that is part of the implementation but not ECMAScript (ed 3 or 5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `obj.hasOwnProperty` filter:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tSnRA/)

This way it will also tell you if contains any properties or if anything is in the prototype chain, if that's what you want.

Alternatively you can change

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
```

to

```
if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
```

if you only want to know if something is messing with it's prototype.

Comment: Could it be ...so simple and obvious? I wonder why my version of the function is the one most typically used (and recommended in dozens of answers on this very site). This indeed works, but I want to plug it into my tests to see if anything blows up unexpectedly.

Comment: @PeterMarks: Generally `hasOwnProperty` is used to ignore properties that are inherited, but since you are interested in inherited props then the filter is counterproductive.

Comment: FWIW, JSlint complains when removing the ``hasOwnProperty`` check. Unsure why though. There is something more to this that I'm not getting.

Comment: It will only test enumerable properties. ES 5 allows the addition of non-enumerable properties, so you still don't know if the object, or something in its prototype chain, has been modified. And what about objects that have enumerable properties (e.g. DOM elements)?

Comment: So I guess the real answer is that you can't tell for sure. Great.