# How to tell if a JavaScript value is an empty object?

Tags: javascript

I came across this issue while debugging an app, and the other answers **do not solve this**!!

With the following use case :

```
class Foo {
  get foo() { return 'foo'; }
}

const value = new Foo();
```

The following [popular solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926112/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-empty) do not work :

```
!Object.keys(value).length;                   // true
!Object.entries(value).length;                // true
!Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).length;    // true
```

Neither is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708263/how-to-test-whether-object-isempty-if-object-prototype-was-modified) :

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
isEmpty(value);                              // true
```

To be clear, `Foo` has a *getter*, and should not be considered empty!

In other words, I expect these results from these use cases :

```
const value1 = new class {};                              // value1 is empty
const value2 = new class { get foo() { return 'foo'; } }  // value2 is not empty
const value3 = {};                                        // value3 is empty
const value4 = { foo:'foo' };                             // value4 is not empty
const value5 = Object.create(null);                       // value5 is empty
const value6 = Object.create(null); value6.foo = 'foo';   // value6 is not empty
```

How can this be evaluated reliably?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: I'm sorry, but while these may provide useful information, a good starting point, they do not answer this specific question.

Comment: That accessor property is being created on the **prototype**, so how do you expect to deal with prototype props? *`Foo`
 has a getter* **No.** `value` has a getter, and it lives on its prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#get_vs._defineproperty):

> When using get the property will be defined on the instance's prototype

In your Foo example:

```js
class Foo {
  get foo() { return 'foo'; }
}

const value = new Foo();

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(value)));
// check if 'empty' (has only "constructor")
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(value)).length === 1);
```

If you want a function that covers all example cases, you can use this:

```js
function isEmpty(obj) {
  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) && (
    proto === null
    || proto === Object.prototype
    || (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto).length === 1)
  );
}

const value1 = new class {};                              // value1 is empty
const value2 = new class { get foo() { return 'foo'; } }  // value2 is not empty
const value3 = {};                                        // value3 is empty
const value4 = { foo:'foo' };                             // value4 is not empty
const value5 = Object.create(null);                       // value5 is empty
const value6 = Object.create(null); value6.foo = 'foo';   // value6 is not empty

[value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6]
  .map((v, i) => `value${i + 1} is ${isEmpty(v) ? "empty" : "not empty"}`)
  .forEach((v) => console.log(v));
```

Comment: I had a similar answer, but your's is prettier! Thanks!